# Using an external xml file for custom list view adapter?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am currently developing my first Android Application. In the app there should be a listView which is displaying at the left side a pic and next to it 2 textViews.

The xml for the listView looks like the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml for the the MainActivity is looking this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView xmlns:android="rowlayout"
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java code looks looks like the following:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    String[] values2 = new String[] {"good","bad","medium","not yet tested","don't know it","very cool","Just Windows","piece of shit","very cool","don't know it too"};
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ListViewAdapter adapter1 = new ListViewAdapter (values,values2,android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
}
```

My current Custom Adapter looks like this:

```
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String[] values;
String[] values2;
Context ctxt;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public ListViewAdapter (String [] Values,String [] Values2, Context context) {
    values = Values;
    values2 = Values2;
    ctxt = context;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    String [] res = new String [] {values [position],values2 [position]};
    return res;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView name1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView name2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    name1.setText(values [position]);
    name2.setText(values2 [position]);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

I get the following error when launching the app:

> Process: de.gotthold.myapplication2.app, PID: 16723
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.gotthold.myapplication2.app/de.gotthold.myapplication2.app.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                   at de.gotthold.myapplication2.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5961)
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>       02-06 12:45:27.641  16723-16723/? D/Process﹕ killProcess, pid=16723
>       02-06 12:45:27.641  16723-16723/? D/Process﹕ com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:138
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690

I would like the get an explanation for this problem, not a link to a tutorial because I tried working trough them and this happend. I read also multiple stackoverflow threads, but none of could solve my problem.

Thanks for your help,
school-guy

P.S.: This is not the app I am developing this is a diffrent one where I am messing around with my new learnt knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code. Let me point them out

**Error 1**

Setting adapter. You cannot call without `setContentView()`

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

You should call

```
 setListAdapter(adapter1);
```

Better way of doing this is:

Use Acticity not ListActivity. Then in `onCreate()` do

```
setConetentView(R.id.Your_main_View);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
ListViewAdapter adapter1 = new ListViewAdapter (values,values2,this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

**Error 2**

Your ListViewAdapter constructor has parameters

```
 (String[] Values,String [], Context)
```

But you are sending

```
 (values,values2,android.R.id.list)
```

You should instead send

```
 (values,values2,this)
```

**Error 3**

You are not inflating the view in the adpater. Without inflating the listView.xml view you cannot convert it to an View type object, thus cannot create a custom listview with it

You should do

```
public static class Holder  //holder class containing view components/widgets
{

    TextView name1,name2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Holder holder=new Holder(); 
View convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list, null);
holder.name1 = convertView.(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
holder.name2 = convertView.(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
holder.name1.setText(values [position]);
holder.name2.setText(values2 [position]);
return convertView;
}
```

For more detail understanding i have written an example  [here](http://www.codedisect.com/?p=100)

Comment: Ok, so good, but why then I need the 2nd argument at error 3?

Comment: by second argument you mean which one? @school_guy

Comment: As you are creating a custom listview you design each row. So your listview.xml is actually a single row of a listview. Now you need to convert it to View object in adapter return to Main listview so that mainlist view gets an object to populate itself. And `R.layout.something` is available to all your class you need not to send it explicitly. @school_guy

Comment: Yeah I read that somewhere, but no matter what object you are using as an argument, you have set it to View convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list, null);

Comment: Now I am getting this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.gotthold.myapplication2.app/de.gotthold.myapplication2.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`

Comment: i have added holder with the code. you may see the edit. But i will really suggest you to see following link to understand better. Its tough to explain things so broad in SO. http://www.codedisect.com/?p=100 @school_guy

Comment: So everything seems to be fine, but now this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.gotthold.myapplication2.app/de.gotthold.myapplication2.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'  @Zahan Safallwa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102788/discussion-between-zahan-safallwa-and-school-guy).

Answer (score 1):

in your `Activity` you are not calling `setContentView` anywhere. Therefore

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

is returning null. Since you are extending `ListActivity`, you don't need to look for the `ListView`.  `ListActivity` has internally one for you. You can submit your adapter calling `setListAdapter`. Remove

```
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter1)
```

and call directly

```
   setListAdapter(adapter1);
```

If you decide to use your own `ListView` for your `Activity`, please make sure to call `setContentView` after `super.onCreate`, change the id of the `ListView` to `@android:id/list`. and look for `android.R.id.list` instead of `R.id.listview`. These are constraints of the `ListActivity`

Comment: Could you take a look at my comment from 15:17 because this seems to be related with your suggested change @Blackbelt

Answer (score 1):

When you use a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), you need to follow a particular pattern to declare a List in the layout and getting a reference to it

You must use `android:id="@android:id/list"` as the ID of the list view.

To get a reference to the list:

Instead of doing this -

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Use the [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView()) convenience method like this -

```
ListView listView = getListView();
```